# oracle 11g r2 install error - ORA-00119: invalid specification for system parameter LOCAL_LISTENER

Tags: database, oracle11g, tnsnames

I keep getting this error after I installed Oracle 11g R2 database server in my 64 bit machine

startup failed: ORA-00119: invalid specification for system parameter LOCAL_LISTENER

ORA-00132: syntax error or unresolved network name 'LISTENER_ORLL', please help.

I can't even modify the spfile because I can't connect to the instance; database has not started, so there is no way to create pfile from spfile.

tnsnames.ora entry

```
   LISTENER_ORLL.WORLD =
    (ADDRESS = 
    (PROTOCOL = TCP)
    (HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
```

listener.ora entry

```
    SID_LIST_LISTENER =(SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\app\username\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
      (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:C:\app\username\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\bin\oraclr11.dll")
    )  )
LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )
```